# How to correctly write string with tabs into file?

Tags: export, named-characters

For example

```
str="a\tb"
```

and

```
str>>"R:\\test.dat"  
(*output "a\tb", with both quotes and \t*)

Export["R:\\test.dat", str];
(*output "a   b". Tab is right, however, quotes is not what I want.*)

WriteString["R:\\test.dat", str];
(*output a\[RawTab]b. Tab is not right*)
```

So how to correctly output strings with tabs to file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always be explicit about the desired format in [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html).  Otherwise, it will try to infer it from the file extension.  And what is `.dat`?  It is a generic, pretty meaningless extension. It does not communicate what format the file follows.

```
Export["filename", str, "String"]
```

[`"String"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/String.html) maintains characters as they are.  [`"Text"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Text.html) can do various conversions, such as character encodings or newline convention.